# Query against a Postgres array column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, array-column

`TL;DR` I'm wondering what the pros and cons are (or if they are even equivalent) between `@> {as_champion, whatever}` and using `IN ('as_champion', 'whatever')` is. Details below:

I'm working with Rails and using Postgres' array column type, but having to use raw sql for my query as the Rails finder methods don't play nicely with it. I found a way that works, but wondering what the preferred method is:

The `roles` column on the `Memberships` table is my array column. It was added via rails as so:

```
add_column :memberships, :roles, :text, array: true
```

When I examine the table, it shows the type as: `text[]` (not sure if that is truly how Postgres represents an array column or if that is Rails shenanigans.

To query against it I do something like:

```
Membership.where("roles @> ?", '{as_champion, whatever}')
```

Comment: The `@>` operator means "contains": it's true if the left-hand array contains all elements in the right-hand array. The `IN` operator is used with basic data types, not arrays.

Comment: @Andomar by basic data types, do you mean `IN` is used just to check if a value is equal to a single string or integer or something in the provided list? Where as `@>` needs to contain all of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the fine [**Array Operators** manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

> Operator: `@>`
>   Description: contains
>   Example: `ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1]`
>   Result: `t` (AKA true)

So `@>` treats its operand arrays as sets and checks if the right side is a subset of the left side.

`IN` is a little different and is used with [subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN):

> **9.22.2. IN**
>
> ```
> expression IN (subquery)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly one column. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each row of the subquery result. The result of `IN` is "true" if any equal subquery row is found. The result is "false" if no equal row is found (including the case where the subquery returns no rows).

or with [literal lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR):

> **9.23.1. IN**
>
> ```
> expression IN (value [, ...])
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions. The result is "true" if the left-hand expression's result is equal to any of the right-hand expressions. This is a shorthand notation for
>
> ```
> expression = value1
> OR
> expression = value2
> OR
> ...
> ```

So `a IN b` more or less means:

> Is the value `a` equal to any of the values in the list `b` (which can be a query producing single element rows or a literal list).

Of course, you can say things like:

```
array[1] in (select some_array from ...)
array[1] in (array[1], array[2,3])
```

but the arrays in those cases are still treated like single values (that just happen to have some internal structure).

---

If you want to check if an array contains any of a list of values then `@>` isn't what you want. Consider this:

```
array[1,2] @> array[2,4]
```

`4` isn't in `array[1,2]` so `array[2,4]` is not a subset of `array[1,2]`.

If you want to check if someone has *both* roles then:

```
roles @> array['as_champion', 'whatever']
```

is the right expression but if you want to check if `roles` is *any* of those values then you want the overlaps operator (`&&`):

```
roles && array['as_champion', 'whatever']
```

Note that I'm using the "array constructor" syntax for the arrays everywhere, that's because it is much more convenient for working with a tool (such as ActiveRecord) that knows to expand an array into a comma delimited list when replacing a placeholder but doesn't fully understand SQL arrays.

Given all that, we can say things like:

```
Membership.where('roles @> array[?]', %w[as_champion whatever])
Membership.where('roles @> array[:roles]', :roles => some_ruby_array_of_strings)
```

and everything will work as expected. You're still working with little SQL snippets (as ActiveRecord doesn't have a full understanding of SQL arrays or any way of representing the `@>` operator) but at least you won't have to worry about quoting problems. You could probably go through AREL to manually add `@>` support but I find that AREL quickly devolves into an incomprehensible and unreadable mess for all but the most trivial uses.

Comment: Amazing answer! For your description of the @> operator, you say it checks if the left side is a subset of the right side, I think you meant *superset*. (I tried to edit it but the change was too small to submit

Comment: @mackshkatz Right, I meant "right side is a subset of left side" (or equivalently, "left side is a superset of right side"). Thanks for pointing that out.